# Typescript: function that returns a predefined union type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Is there a way in TypeScript to model a function that can return an already specified union type, like `myFunc` in the example below?

```
type UnionType = {
  field: "one",
  value: "two"
} | {
  field: "a" | "b",
  value: "a1" | "b1" | "c1"
}

myFunc("one", "two") // OK
myFunc("a", "a1") // OK
myFunc("a", "b1") // OK
myFunc("b", "a1") // OK

myFunc("one", "a1") // ERROR: only allowed second argument should be "two"
myFunc("one", "a") // ERROR: only allowed second argument should be "two"
myFunc("a", "two") // ERROR: only allowed second argument should be "a1" or "b1" or "c1"
```

A first naive approach might be something like this:

```
const myFunc = <T extends UnionType>(field: T["field"], value: T["value"]): UnionType => ({
  field,
  value,
})
```

Which doesn't compile because the arguments are not dependent. Somehow I need `value` to be constrained by the type of `field`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
type InferValue<T extends UnionType, K extends UnionType["field"]> = 
// Use `extends` keyword to limit, refer to TypeScript `Exclude` implementation
T extends (
  // get the matching struct, but it cannot be used directly
  {
    field: K;
    value: any;
  } extends T
    ? T
    : never
)
  ? T["value"]
  : never;

const myFunc = <K extends UnionType["field"]>(
  field: K,
  value: InferValue<UnionType, K>
): any => ({ // any
  field,
  value,
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, this is almost exactly what I needed! I was trying to wrap my head on why `myFunc` needs to return `any`, as it looks like it's not necessary. Furthermore, for my use-case I'd need `myFunc` to specifically return `UnionType`. For now a I got around it with a type assertion on the returned object but I'm trying to see if there is a way to avoid it.

Comment: return `any ` is not important, you can also use `as UnionType`